# Increase the logo size in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-apps, lightning-experience

In salesforce lightning experience i've tried to change the logo size but it's not working it is appearing small in lightning pages. How can we increase the size?

Comment: What exactly did you try so far?

Comment: Follow steps from this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131986/change-salesforce-logo-on-lightning

Answer (score 1):

As of Summer '17, I have not found an out-of-the-box way to increase the size. The App Manager is expecting a 45x45 pixels square image. If you use a non-square, then the longer dimension will max at 45px, resulting in the shorter side being very short.

UPDATE: Override global styles

I found a way around the square logo limitations. I added CSS to a custom Lightning Component and then added to the page via the Lightning App Builder.

This is the CSS you need: `<style>.slds-global-header__logo{width: auto !important;}</style>`

Note that this needs to go in the `.cmp` file itself and not in the styles file of the bundle. Then you need to make sure this component is added to whatever page(s) load first when you load the Salesforce org.

This isn't a perfect solution, and you're definitely going to have some scenarios where people come in via direct links to some page that hasn't loaded this custom component, but at least it's a workaround.